# Release to Maven Central with submodules

Tags: java, maven

I have a project with several modules. I use the pom packaging for most of them and there are of course some jar modules.
Now, I need to deploy on Maven Central. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/01/08/deploy-to-maven-central-repository/).

When I run the proposed sh script

```
!/bin/bash
read -p "Really deploy to maven central repository  (yes/no)? "
if ( [ "$REPLY" == "yes" ] ) then
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ssh-add -l
  mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -B -e | tee maven-central-deploy.log
  ssh-add -D
else
  echo 'Exit without deploy'
fi
```

at step

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform -B -e | tee maven-central-deploy.log
```

The command fails miserably at `perform` step with the following message that I do not understand

```
INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project blaster-core: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I think that everything is ok. May it be that it is because I added the following only in the modules with jar packaging?

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and the profile is:

```
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.6</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                        <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solved.

I replaced the `distributionManagement` part as

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And I put this part and the `release` profile in all the modules. I'm pretty sure that I can inherit this somehow, but for now it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

> May it be that it is because I added the following only in the modules with jar packaging?

Yes, if you're running the release from the top level of the project structure, and a module can't find a definition of its `<distributionManagement>`, then Maven won't know how to release that module.  The recommended approach is to define `<distributionManagement>` in a parent pom.xml that all other modules in the project inherit from.  That way, the settings are maintained in a single location.

> ...I don't need to release the modules with pom packaging but just those with jar packaging.

I assume the reason you are using pom packaging is that some of these jar modules are using project inheritance to inherit from the pom modules.  If so, then you do in fact need to release the modules that use pom packaging.  This is because when other projects use a `<dependency>` on your jar module, Maven must be able to find the parent pom.xml too in order to fully resolve the definition of that project, for relevant things like finding all transitive dependencies.

Comment: I added the missing part in the main pom but I still have the same problem. I also added the configuration from the pom